# Removing the Save button based on some condition

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, modules, hook, button

I want to remove the Create button of an entry based on some condition (review states) for some users.

Is there a way to hook in within a module?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do this via JS, using https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-js

If the information, whether you want to show the button or not, is not available in the entry's edit page itself, create a controller within a module and request the information from the controller via AJAX.